# assigning a string vs assigning the fields of a structure

Tags: c

So I know if you have two strings you need strcpy to assign one to the other, you can't use =.
But say you have a structure like

```
typedef struct{
char name[15];
int age;}person;
```

and you have

```
person q,f;
q=f;
```

this will assign all the fields of f to q. But there's a string in there f.name. How does that work? Shouldn't the string in there cause a problem. I'm new to coding and that's confusing me a bit.

Comment: It’s like if you had `char name0; char name1; char name2; … char name14;`.

Answer (score 3):

Each field is populated with a value equal to the corresponding field in the source structure.

For example, it could possibly be implemented using

```c
memcpy(&q, &f, sizeof(struct person));
```

This means the following is perfectly legit:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   char name[15];
   int age;
} Person;

int main(void) {
   Person f = { "abc", 30 };
   Person q;
   q = f;
   printf("%s\n", q.name);  // abc
   printf("%d\n", q.age);   // 30
}
```

(I find it useful to use uppercase for types. Then, you can do `Person person;`.)

(Do note that I had to initialize `f` before performing the assignment to avoid undefined behaviour.)

---

In the above, changing `f.name` or `q.name` (after the assignment) has no effect on the other. However, consider what happens if you had the following instead:

```
typedef struct {
   char *name;
   int age;
} Person2;
```

Again, (only) a field-for-field copy is made, you'll end up with the same pointer (pointing to the same object) in both structures.

Comment: Re “I don't what the C spec says about any padding”: An assignment stores the semantic value of the right operand, converted to the type of the left operand, in the left operand. The value of a structure includes only the values of its members, not the contents of any padding bytes. C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 explicitly says that when a value is stored in a structure (not just a member of a structure), its padding bytes take unspecified values.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Thought so. I was trying to keep it simple, though I kinda failed at that while still making claims that weren't completely true. Fixed. Feel free to keep the comment since it provides the spec's wording for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason a modern compiler could not copy an array, making an assignment like `a = b;` work if `a` and `b` were suitable arrays. That includes copying the characters of a string, as with `a = "abc";`.

However, when C was being developed, it was very much a give-the-computer-each-instruction-yourself kind of language, and copying a “big” thing like an array was not suitable for the hardware and the programming situations of the time. You also could not copy structures in early versions of C.

Instead, to help programmers deal with arrays, features were added to automatically convert arrays to pointers, so programmers could easily write their own code to copy arrays or to manipulate their contents, as in:

```
for (char *p = array; *p; ++p)
   *d++ = *p;
```

Over the years, hardware became more powerful, and C grew to be used more and more. The ability to copy structures using assignments was added. However, by then, the convert-array-to-pointer feature was built into the language and could not be changed. Thus, we cannot make `a = b;` copy arrays because it does not mean “Assign the value of array `b` to array `a`”; it would mean “Assign the address of the first element of `b` to the address of the first element of `a`.”

Aside from using `memcpy`, other workarounds could be devised, but it has simply not proven valuable enough to add any special provision for assigning arrays to the language.

So the presence of an array of characters inside a structure is not a problem: There is no rule in C that you cannot copy arrays. It is simply that there is no way to express an assignment that copies an array. Assignments that copy structures are easy to express, and they simply copy the contents of the structures.